# What is the appropriate way to respond to dismissive or otherwise negative comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, offensive

I've been exploring several Stack Exchange sites this morning and I've noticed that at least one community (which will go unnamed) has had needlessly aggressive, negative, and dismissive comments to upvoted questions given its subject area. I would *not* ask questions on Stack Exchange sites if this was the expected reaction to my posts, and thankfully I have never experienced such rude feedback. Suppose, however, I saw such comments in response to one of my questions or answers, or in response to a well-worded, polite question or answer asked by another. What is the best way to respond?

Comment: It would help to answer this better if you provided some examples of such comments.

Comment: I'd like to preserve anonymity of the posters, if I could, so I'm happy with more general advice. (Plus I didn't make a point of jotting them down.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> } ***What is the best way to respond?***

1. If the comment's content has something constructive, take that constructive part into account (either inwardly be learning from it, or outwardly by trying to incorporate the feedback into the post).
2. If the tone was rude, to an extent of violation of "Be nice" policy, **flag the comment for the moderator attention**. That's basically what the flags are for.

   This is a wee bit tricky, since we meatbags are prone to be biased to consider any criticism as rude. So, I would recommend NOT flagging in a heat of the moment but taking a bit of time to cool off and consider.

   On the other hand, don't be afraid to flag. If you have a tendency to be overly sensitive and flag things that aren't actually rude, you will get feedback in the form of rejected flags and rejection explanations, and you can effectively use that to calibrate your opinions and expectations.
3. Do **NOT** respond in comments of your own. No matter how tempting it is.

   *(this is the point where I suppose I look in the mirror and award myself a shiny new `[hypocrite]` badge :)*

   If the comment was truly rude, it's not your job to engage (it's moderators'). If it wasn't rude and it's just your perception, you just escalated the situation needlessly AND made yourself look bad to other users.

Answer (score 2):

For every dismissive, negative, or "whatever you called them" comments, you better flag them for moderator attention! That is what flagging is for! I had to flag a Math.SE comment (which will remain anonymous) because the commentor was being rude to the OP of the question in which the comment was in. So to make things simple, flag it down!

Comment: I'll do that! The community in question had a _lot_ of negative comments, so perhaps doing so there is an uphill battle I'll avoid fighting :P (which is sad, given how useful that community's content is).

Comment: Now "that's the spirit"! Fighting back creates flamewars, which can lead to a whole lot of problems!